# Rascal: Containing Imported Symbols

Tags: import, read-eval-print-loop, rascal

I work with multiple grammars in the repl. The grammars use same names for some of their rules.

One of the documentation recipes [mentions full qualification](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Recipes.html#/Recipes/Languages/Exp/Combined/Manual/Manual.html), to disambiguate type annotations in function pattern matching (it's in a note of the `load` function, but not in the code of this page - the .jar has it correct). But that might become tedious, so maybe there is aliasing for imports (like in Python `import regex as r`)?! And using full qualification in the first argument of the `parse` function doesn't seem to help to disambiguate all parse rules that are invoked recursively, `parse(#lang::java::\syntax::Java18::CompilationUnit, src)`. At least it produces weird errors if I also import lang::java::\syntax::Java15.

In general, what is a safe way to handle symbols from different modules with same names?

Alternatively, is there a way to "unload" a module in the repl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background information:

1. Rascal modules are *open* for reasons of extensibility, in particular `data`, `syntax` definitions and overloaded functions can be extended by importing another module; In this way you can extend a language and its processing functions by importing another module and adding rules and function alternatives at leisure.
2. There is a semantic difference between `import`ing and `extend`ing a module. In particular `import` is not transitive and fuses only the uses of a name inside the importing module, while `extend` *is* transitive and also fuses recursive uses of a name in the module that is extended. So for extending a language, you'd default to using `extend`, while for using a library of functions you'd use `import`.
3. We are planning to remove the `fusing` behavior from `import` completely in one of the releases of 2020. After this all conflictingly imported non-terminal names must be disambiguated by prefixing with the module name, and prefixing will not have a side-effect of fusing recursively used non-terminals from different modules anymore. Not so for `extend`, which will still fuse the non-terminal and functions all the way.
4. all the definitions in a REPL instance simulate the semantics of the members of a single anonymous module.

So to answer your questions:

- it's *not* particularly safe to handle symbols from different imported modules with the same name, until we fix the semantics of `import` that is.
- the module prefix trick only works "top-level", below this the types are fused anyway because the code which reifies a non-terminal as a grammar does not propagate the prefix. It wouldn't know how.
- Unimporting a module:

  ```
  rascal>import IO;
  ok
  rascal>println("x");
  x
  ok
  rascal>:un
  undeclare   unimport    
  rascal>:unimport IO
  ok
  rascal>println("x");
  |prompt:///|(0,7,<1,0>,<1,7>): Undeclared variable: println
  ```

  - probably one of the least used features in the environment; caveat emptor!

To work around these issues, a way is to write functions inside a different module for every separate language/language version, and create a top module which imports these if you want to bundle the functionality in a single interface. This way, because `import` is not transitive, the namespaces stay separate and clean. Of course this does not solve the REPL issue; the only thing I can offer there is to start a fresh REPL for each language version you are playing with.

Comment: Great, thanks for the additional details. Any planning on the side of allowing aliases for imported libraries?

Comment: No not yet; but feel free to suggest it on github :-)

Comment: As for `unimport`, is this a rather new feature? Starting a fresh repl and importing IO, `un<tab>` only produces `unregisterLocations`. The repl says my Rascal version is 0.16.2. Is it too old? Also, the repl doesn't know `extend`. Should that be a repl command too?

Comment: It's `:unimport`, all REPL commands which are not strictly members of modules, start with a colon. Like `:quit` and `:edit <modulename>` and such.

Comment: version 0.16.2 is the latest stable from December. that is the recommended release right now.

Comment: my REPL does know `extend`, like so: `rascal>extend IO;`

Comment: Ah, right. `:unimport` is there and works. And `extend` is also there, it just appears some commands are not tab-completed, so `ext<tab>` did not yield `extend`. But now I know ...